# How to make a dynamic timeline using bootstrap?

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a dynamic timeline like facebook that can post pictures and descriptions with dates using mysql php for database. I put bootstrap because I like their design, and it's easy to use.

My problem is i don't know where to begin or where do I study it.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image: Example]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi TKGhoul, Welcome to StackOverflow!  For the best responses, questions here usually need to focus on a specific problem you're trying to solve. You can try taking this type of question to [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) or some other more generic forums on reddit.  You have a long way to go before your timeline is facebook-like, so start diving into specific stuff and come back when you get stuck along the way.  There's no one "right" way to build a vertical timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a generic question... this seems to me an impossible question to answer but maybe you need just some little advices to begin studying the right languages which you can use to achieve what you want.

First of all please provide an image of what you want to do and more important the fundamental languages that you have to know are HTML (obviously), CSS, Javascript and PHP for some server side script.

Talking specifically about your problem, here is where you can see some open examples with well commented code that allows you to understand everything.

[http://www.jqueryrain.com/2015/05/ideabox-jquery-timeline-news-ticker/](https://web.archive.org/web/20170603114801/http://www.jqueryrain.com/2015/05/ideabox-jquery-timeline-news-ticker/)
[http://www.jqueryrain.com/2014/11/vertical-timeline-css3-jquery/](https://web.archive.org/web/20170515101900/https://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/)

Comment: my bad i can't post pictures my rep is under 10. But here's the image link http://blog.tmimgcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/2014.04.23-900x538.jpg?0df779 or a facebook wall timeline.

Comment: very well, so I think that the linked I passed you before was right :)
Again: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?ODA3Rflq